# Kafka exaclty one delivery semantics on error scenarios

Tags: apache-kafka, messaging, kafka-producer-api

In the documentation is stated

```
From Kafka 0.11, the KafkaProducer supports two additional modes: the idempotent producer
and the transactional producer. The idempotent producer strengthens Kafka's delivery  
semantics from at least once to exactly once delivery.
...

To take advantage of the idempotent producer, it is imperative to avoid application
level re-sends since these cannot be de-duplicated. As such, if an application enables
idempotence, it is recommended to leave the retries config unset, as it will be defaulted
to Integer.MAX_VALUE. Additionally, if a send(ProducerRecord) returns an error even with
infinite retries (for instance if the message expires in the buffer before being sent),
then it is recommended to shut down the producer and check the contents of the last
produced message to ensure that it is not duplicated.
Finally, the producer can only guarantee idempotence for messages sent within a single session.
```

I don't exactly understand how to avoid application level resends in failure scenarios, particularly in the scenarios when ACKs are lost due to network error in combination with the producer app being down.

Would you be able to point me to the strategies used to ensure exactly once delivery ?

Comment: Have you tried building a POC? When transactions are started and ended, there are markers placed in the topic. Any event that's received outside of that could be a duplicate, but it should be ignored by enabling read-isolation on the consumer

Comment: In this part the documentation does not mention transactions, it's just referring to to idempotent producers.

Comment: I think it mentions it. First sentence says "and the transactional producer"